# Feedback form - how can we implement this?

Tags: php

I have 5 persons responsible for sending feedback forms.

I need to later on the process, understand for all of those persons, who as received more filled forms.

There is no login system. The forms will be sent by email.

I'm thinking about creating 5 separate forms, and on each of those, have a hidden field with some id. Based on that, when the form data is saved on the database, that id will be saved as well.

A simple count() may return the data needed.

HOWEVER, I do think that perhaps, there is a better, simpler, logical approach to grab this information ?

I believe that having 5 different forms where only a hidden field is the difference, is a dummy idea.

Update:
Can we fill in that hidden field with different data based on what person has sent the form ?
I'm not seeing if this is possible.

Or, another idea, can we, have a .htaccess that will popup a username / password window, and based on that credentials, display a form with an hidden field associated with that (username / password) credentials ?

Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And why cannot those persons fill in their nickname/login/identificator into a separate field?

Or do You want them not to know about counting their responses...?

Comment: Sorry, not following. Those 5 persons need to send the forms so that other persons could filled in. Those forms will be sent by email to several different emails. They cannot send the form, and then, fill it, unless, there is some sort of way to, when the formed is sent, the field nick/id/indentifier is already filled in. Was this what you meant ?

Comment: What he meant was to make another field where you input your name or id, and you can track the amount of forms filled based on this input.

Comment: Ahh. I see. Indeed that makes sense. :) I was focus on a hidden field hm? :s Oh well. ;) Thanks. :D

Comment: @Zirak or Shaddyx I still have a question here: we need to somehow, automatic count that data. Since it seems that we don't need a database, what can we think of, to do such counts ? A txt file that will have a value incremented ? Or perhaps something simpler ?

Comment: The simplest way should be to increment a value in a simple file. But this brings us a conflict state when twor or more people would try to increment the value in the file at the very same time... Database is better and not so complicated to handle these counts... You can also store more data (whole data from forms being sent) and then do just `SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl WHERE login = '<<LOGIN>>'`